# how to link staticially with third party libraries in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am wondering how to link third party libraries in visual studio?

the third party I mean they gave you *.dll, *.lib and *.pdb.

for example, zmq:

```
lib/
    libzmq-v100-mt-gd-3_2_4.lib (static library)
    libzmq-v100-mt-gd-3_2_4.pdb (debug file)
bin/
    libzmq-v100-mt-gd-3_2_4.dll (dynamic library)
```

my vs project need libzmq, and I want to link zmq statically. however, I looked 
at project property pages. there is no option to allow us force the program linked statically or dynamically. (perhaps, I missed something)

I set linker/general, linker/input, c_c++/general (include) to the corresponding zmq path. But, it does not work.

Comment: You can't link it statically, you got a DLL.  Keep looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libzmq-v100-mt-gd-3_2_4.lib` in this case is the import library rather than the full static library. Linking against `libzmq-v100-mt-gd-3_2_4.lib` will result in your application requiring `libzmq-v100-mt-gd-3_2_4.dll`.

You'll need to either build a static library from source if they don't provide one, or use it as a DLL.